# Android - where and how to store static mixed data for the UI

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragments

My application has a MainMenuActivity with 3 tabs pointing to 3 fragments. On these fragments there are multiple menu items.

```
Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab3
-------=======------
Menu Item 2.1
Menu Item 2.2
Menu Item 2.3
```

I am used to PHP and its multidimensional mixed-type arrays. In PHP I would store the hierarchical structure of the main menu like this and iterate through it to create a menu html:

```
$mainMenu = array(
    ...
    'tab2' => array(
        'label' => 'Tab 1',
        'items' => array(
            'item1' => array(
                'label' => 'Menu Item 2.1',
                'activity' => 'activity1',
                'icon' => 'icon_x',
                ...
            ),
            'item2' => array(
                'label' => 'Menu Item 2.2',
                'activity' => 'activity2'
                'icon' => 'icon_y',
                ...
            ),
            ...
        )
    ),
    ...
);
```

I am aware of the fact that Java has much more strict policy with arrays. At first I thought I should create a MainMenuItem class with properties (int tabId, String label, String activity etc), then create an array of instantiated objects of this class. But where should I instantiate them? In the Activity? In the Fragment?

Another thought was to store it in SQLite DB.

Other possible solutions?

What would be the best practice for this and similar situations?